# $browser not defined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jquery for browser detection but it says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $browser is not defined

the code is like

```
if(!$browser.msie){
   condition
 }
```

Comment: Can you even use Jquery? Is '$' defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$browser` is not defined because [the `browser` property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is defined as a part of the `jQuery` (or `$`) object.

In other words, use `$.browser` or `jQuery.browser`, not `$browser`.

Answer (score 7):

$.browser was removed in jquery 1.9. See http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed

Answer (score 6):

`browser` is a property on the main jQuery object: `if(!$.browser.msie){ ... }`

**Please note that since the time of posting, this property has been removed in jQuery 1.9.**

Comment: Too bad i can't delete my comment, didn't realize this was an old thread.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dot:

```
$.browser
```

Check out the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$.browser.msie
```

or

```
jQuery.browser.msie
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `$.browser`, not `$browser`

```
if($.browser.msie) ...
```