# How to retrieve selected drop-down values from external plugin?

Tags: html, css, performance, jquery-plugins

I'm using [plugin](http://www.givainc.com/labs/mcdropdown_jquery_plugin.cfm) from drop-down, all is set, except I cannot get values of drop-down items as they are selected.

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mcdropdown.js"></script>
<!---// load the mcDropdown CSS stylesheet //--->
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mcdropdown.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>


<style type="text/css">
div.test > div {
    float: left;
    width: 108px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
div.mcdropdown {
    width: 110px;
}
ul.mcdropdown_menu {
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="categorymenu" class="mcdropdown_menu">
    <li rel="1">Arts &amp; Humanities
    <ul>
        <li rel="2">Photography
        <ul>
            <li rel="3">3D </li>
            <li rel="4">Digital </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li rel="5">History </li>
        <li rel="6">Literature </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li rel="7">Business &amp; Economy </li>
    <li rel="8">Computers &amp; Internet </li>
    <li rel="9">Education </li>
    <li rel="11">Entertainment
    <ul>
        <li rel="12">Movies </li>
        <li rel="13">TV Shows </li>
        <li rel="14">Music </li>
        <li rel="15">Humor </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li rel="10">Health </li>
</ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function check()
{

  var mc=  $("#category").mcDropdown();

        alert(mc.getValue());

}
</script>
```

According to doc `When a user selects an item from the menu, it is this value that is placed in a hidden  element and therefore passed back to the server when the form is submitted.`, I want to know the value of selected item, but the js only gives me rel number in integer no value, how can I get values or I can self post on submit button to a function where I can see how these values are being sent.

THANKS.

Comment: Why do you have `style` section out of `head` section? And there are two `}` extra at the end.

Comment: @AntoJurkovic bad formatting I will fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code with minor fixes I got the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined jquery.mcdropdown.js:78`

Line 78 from plugin:

```
var isIE6 = ($.browser.version && $.browser.version <= 6);
```

But $browser property was removed with jQuery version 1.9. See [$browser not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5889279/browser-not-defined).

So, if you are using lates version of jQuery, try with some older one.

It works with jQuery version 1.2.6. and 1.7.0. Did not test with in-between versions. For example with include:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't work with 1.8.3. Reports error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new v.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'curCSS' jquery.mcdropdown.js:694
```

With a little help from google it got the following:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    // dropdown reference and dropdown value
    var dd, val;

    // the option object to pass to mcDropdown
    // set neccessary callbacks
    var options = new Object();
    options.select = selectHandler;
    options.init   = initHandler;

    // initialize DOM element for mcDropdown
    $('#category').mcDropdown('#categorymenu', options);

    // create a reference to the dropdown
    // here you can set initial value
    function initHandler() {
        // get a copy of the object
        dd = $('#category').mcDropdown();

        // dd.setValue(yourID);
    }

    // called whenever someone changes a selection on mcDropdown
    function selectHandler() {
        val = dd.getValue();
        console.log(val);
    }
});
```

and in console for different selections:

```
"9", ""] 
["12", "Education"]
["10", "Entertainment:Movies"]
```

Comment: please see my update i told form to send data to function, where i initialized the function and using getValue its public function i get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Heads up for this awesome `jQuery` plugin for retrieving selected drop-down
values: http://loudev.com/#demos licensed under ["DO WHAT THE F*** YOU WANT TO PUBLIC LICENSE"](http://www.wtfpl.net/txt/copying/).